# .firstIndex always returning nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to download a file from a server and then parse the file into a array of structs and then look through the array and search a particular value and when I find the value return the value, However the .firstIndex is always returning nil

```
// Function to return an array of MachineDetails struct based on Machines.txt file
func getMachineDetails(completionHandler: @escaping ([MachineDetails]? , Error?) -> Void) {
    var details = [MachineDetails]()
    let url = URL(string: "https:somefile.txt")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (urlOrnil, responseOrNil, errorOrNil) in
        guard let fileURL = urlOrnil else { return }
        do {
            guard let contents = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL) else { throw errorOrNil! }
            let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")
            for line in lines {
                let entries = line.split(separator: ";").map { String($0) }
                if entries.count == 4 {
                    let newMachine = MachineDetails(machineNumber:entries[0],
                                                    machineName:entries[1],
                                                    machineXML:entries[2],
                                                    machineWiFi:entries[3])
                    details.append(newMachine)
                } else {
                    print("Malformed line \(line)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("file error: \(error)")
        }
        completionHandler(details, nil)
    }
    task.resume()
```

}

```
// Function to get the machine name from machine number
func getMachineName(machineNumber: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    getMachineDetails { (machineDetails, error) in
        if let machineDetails = machineDetails {
            print(machineDetails)
            let index = machineDetails.firstIndex { $0.machineNumber == machineNumber }
            if index != nil {
               // nothing gets printed here because index is always nil
                print("index is \(String(describing: index))")
            }
        // This always fails because index is nil
        completion(machineDetails[index!].machineName)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step through?  Is there anything in your `MachineDetails` array?  Is there an element with the right property you are looking for?

Comment: yes machine details array is full and has the property I'm looking for. when I do print(machineDetails) I get the results and the value I'm looking for is there

Comment: Could you give the output of ` print(machineDetails)`? Also, could you add `print(machineDetails.map{ $0.machineNUmber }.joined(separator: ", "))`?

Comment: @Larme please see updated question

Comment: What you have shown for `print(MachineDetails)` does not look correct.  You should not see any ; please edit your question to show what you actually get in the console.

Comment: Are you sure the output you added is from the print statement in the code and not some other print statement, maybe your code never calls getMachineName?

Comment: `print(machineDetails)` => `print("machineDetails response: \(machineDetails)")`. What's the EXACT output of that one?

Comment: @Larme I get machineDetails response: [] as a response, but somehow I get the machine details printed eventhough I'm not printing it anywhere

Comment: Just before `completionHandler(details, nil)`, could you add `print("Details before completionHandler: \(details)")`? I guess they are nil? What you previsouly shown as "printed", what not an array of `MachineDetails`, it was the raw text file. Now, add debug steps: add separate prints, to know what's happening or use breakpoint. Also `var details = [MachineDetails]()` should be inside the closure, not outside.

Comment: @Larme printing before the completion handler is an empty array as well -> Details before completionHandler: []

Comment: Could you add: `print("Contents: \(contents)")`? And `lines.count`. As you noticed, I always put something before the print of the value to know from where it's coming. I never just do `print(value)`, always `print("value in: \(value)')` so I always know.

Comment: contents show Contents: 17.03.2021 11:18:21.81 and lines.count show 1, I think it only reads the first line of the file, and exits, the first line should be skipped anyway, as it shows it's the date the file is created, the real contents are after that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230254/discussion-between-larme-and-akano1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug.

After debugging, we found that:

`completionHandler(details, nil)`, `details` is empty.

`let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")`, `lines.count` is `1`. What you havent' said, is that the first line was not a "Raw Machine Details", but file infos. So it was skipped, but then, the rest was never parsed.
Instead of using the "\n" separator, use: `let lines = contents.components(separatedBy: .newlines)`

And then, your parsing should work.

Now `var details = [MachineDetails]()` should be inside the `downloadTask(with: completionHandler:)` closure.
You don't seem to return nil array, empty one, but not nil, so use `@escaping ([MachineDetails] , Error?) -> Void)`?